# Constant expression with casting uint to float in GLSL

Tags: constants, glsl, vulkan

I defined a global constant like this

```
const uint Y = 4;
const float X = float(Y);
```

It works just fine. Now I would like to make it a bit more flexible by using specialization constants

```
layout (constant_id = 1) const uint Y = 4;
const float X = float(Y);
```

Unfortunately now I get

```
error: '=' : global const initializers must be constant ' const highp float'
```

Why is it that GLSL cannot perform such simple conversion in the presence of specialization constants? Shouldn't specialization constants be treated on equal with any other constant expression? Is it really the case that the only possible solution to this problem is to provide both constants using

```
layout (constant_id = 1) const uint Y = 4;
layout (constant_id = 2) const float X = 4.;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Vulkan GLSL specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt), only certain operators can be used on a specialization constant in order for it to remain a specialization constant. Converting one to a `float` isn't on that list.

As for why you can't do this, it's because Vulkan compilers should be as simple as possible. When you have a specialization constant and perform some operation on it and try to use it as a constant, the compiler has to invisibly perform that operation at specialization time. That's a big pain for the implementation to do, so Vulkan GLSL restricts how much of this is needed.

The Vulkan GLSL specification contains something of a bug. It's non-normative text says that this is possible:

> ```
> layout(constant_id = 18) const int scX = 1;
> layout(constant_id = 19) const int scZ = 1;
> const vec3 scVec = vec3(scX, 1, scZ);  // partially specialized vector
> ```

But the section "Specialization Constant Operations" specifically says that it isn't, due to the implicit conversion from `int` to `float`.